# Why is my view context not displaying in this case?

Tags: python, django

[image][image]

I should be seeing a value displayed right next to "Notifications" and before the exclamation symbol.

Just as it sounds, I cannot display a context variable "{{ var }}" provided in a view. I've tried cbv and function based views.

*In this project I am using Django 2.1 and Python alias is set as 3.6*

This is the first sort of view I used, simply to display a number:

```
class NotificationView(DetailView):
    template_name = "base.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        message_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=self.request.user).count()
        safeTrans_count = SafeTransaction.objects.filter(trans_recipient=self.request.user).count()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["Notify"] = message_count + safeTrans_count
        return context
```

This is the second sort of view, I tried to make the simplest possible function that would display a context:

```
def NotifyView(request):
    title = "Notification View %s" % (request.user)
    context = {
        "Notification_Count": 10,
        "Notification_Title": title,
    }
    return render(request, "base.html", context)
```

This is a snippet of the template used to display (Variables such as {{Notification_Title}} simply do not display at all) :

```
       {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="active-2" href="#">Notifications{{Notification_Title}} 
          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle">
          </i>
        </a>
       {% else %}
```

[image: This is what the terminal looks like right now, no obvious errors for the behaviour]

Any ideas as to what I could be overlooking would be very much appreciated.

:::

Here is my solution for this particular problem. Please let me know if there is a better way to display the values without having to pass user in the actual template tag on the template as:`{% notify user %}`

[image]

Comment: The second Python snippet is rather garbled (invalid syntax).

Comment: What do you see? What is the actual problem?

Comment: I'll add a screenshot image illustrating what I see.

Comment: Sorry @AKX, I only just noticed that, I believe it must have copy paste slip up on my part, I believe I've corrected it now.

Comment: Looking at the code, there's nothing immediately wrong. Have you configured `TEMPLATES` somehow specially? Are you sure all files you're editing what you expect (for example you're not accidentally editing a wrong copy of a template)?

Comment: @AKX I do believe I am editing only one copy of "base.html"
Should I also include the part of my settings.py file showing the template related configurations ?

Comment: Can you show your urls? Have you mapped the base route to your notify view? (Note also that your CBV sets the key "Notify", not "Notification_Title".)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I realise the discrepancy in Notify and Notification_Title, I just changed it in the template as required.                                                      As for the urls I've added a path: `path('', NotificationView.as_view() , name='Notify'),` to no effect

Comment: I'll just edit and add my Url.py snippet

Comment: But you can't have two patterns for the same path. Your base route will be served by `views.index`, not the notification view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But the base.html is a template file that is inherited from in the first place, there shouldn't really be a path that explicitly references it.
I will remove that path nonetheless

Comment: But something has to call the view. If you don't have a URL pointing at it, then nothing will call it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177292/discussion-between-timi95-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about the relationship between URLs, views and templates. A URL calls a view, which (potentially) renders a template. That view is therefore responsible for providing all the information necessary for rendering the template.  You can't just define a completely separate view and expect its information to somehow find its way into the template.

If you have data which needs to be provided to templates by multiple views, you can use a number of approaches - shared base view classes, context processors, or custom template tags.

Comment: Here is what the entire base.html looks as.
index.html and everything else is inheriting from this file, shouldn't they also inherit context ?

https://pastebin.com/KXbAQy61

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with inheritance. You have things backwards in your head. The base URL calls the index view, which renders the template. Your notify view is never called, because the only thing that calls a view is a URL.

Comment: Okay I see, then is there a way for me to call both views.index and NotificationsView.as_view() in the same line, or must I neccessarily rewire it so that everything starts with /index/<path> and my base.html path is '' ?

Comment: like this : ` path('', (views.index,NotificationsViews.as_view()) , name='index'),`

or like this : [  path('', NotificationsView.as_view() , name='index'),
 path('index', views.index , name='index'),
]

?

Comment: No you still haven't understood. Even if you did do that it wouldn't help, because the index view needs the data at the time it renders the template. I told you the way to do this: contact l context processors or template tags.

Comment: Okay, I will attempt to do something with template tags now, I will take reference from django documentation. Will report back if it fails or I still have not understood.

Comment: I've spent the rest of the day reading about custom template tags;My current plan is to sort of create another template displaying the context, then utilising inclusion tags, in order to bring it in to  my base.html.

Will this work, is it worth trying ?
Is there a simpler way to use custom template tags ?
Maybe Simple tags perhaps ?

Currently just trying to successfully implement some of the examples on the django documentation, but running into lots of new errors, this is making me even slower than usual.

Comment: Yes the inclusion tag will work, or you can use a simple tag to just display your notification count directly in the base template. Either is fine.

Comment: Yes, the simple tag does display values, however. I had some parameters in the filter option for my object queries, self.request.user. I cannot put these as arguments in the simple_tag function because that will change its behaviour. I only want it to behave like a variable. `Message.objects.filter(recipient=self.request.user).count()` how to include or instantiate self.request.user in the simple tag function, is now what I need. Will you tell me how to do this also please ?

Comment: You can use the `takes_context=True` parameter in the decorator to ensure that the full context - including `request` - is passed to the tag function.